quaternionic unitary group isomorphism
The compact symplectic group consist of all unitary matrices that preserve a non-degenerate anti-symmetric bilinear form ( $U \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$).
It is the same as the quaternionic unitary group ($Q \in \mathbb{H}^{n/2 \times n/2}$).
So there must be an isomorphism between both.
Now if I want to operate on $ \mathbb{H}^{n/2 \times n/2}$, how would I transform for $x\in \mathbb{C}^{n} \mapsto \tilde{x} \in \mathbb{H}^{n/2}$ s.t. $Q\tilde{x}$ is consistent with the outcome of $Ux$?
And how would I transform the other way around $ \tilde{x} \in  \mathbb{H}^{n/2}$ to $x \in \mathbb{C}^{n} $ properly?

The quaternions can be represented using complex $2\times 2$ matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix}z & w\
-\bar w & \bar z\end{pmatrix}$, where $z,w\in\mathbb C$. Maybe this can help.
